# Shut Down Node Instance from Code

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using express with domain.js middle ware.

I need to be able to shut down the node instance from a request. This is not a public facing instance so security is not really an issue. I am using express to process http request, one of which is a "kill" request. This request should shut down node completely as quickly as possible.

I've tried the following `server.close()`, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

I would rather shut it down as gracefully as possible, but if I need to kill it I am willing to do that. I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

[`process.exit(exitCode)`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) should do.

Answer (score 2):

just call `process.exit(exitCode)`, it will exit

Answer (score 2):

```
app.get('/kill', function(req,res) {
    process.exit(0);
});
```

The exit code can be anything. But any non-zero value means unclean exit.